# AcquireTokenSilentAsync never using tokens from the cache

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a class that acts as a wrapper for the MS Graph SDK. Fairly simple purpose, inside the class there are methods for getting various data sets out of Graph for a particular user.

EDIT: this runs under the context of an application, so no user creds are ever used.

All of that part works fine, what isn't working is the `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` never finds the access token in the cache. Each call to a graph endpoint gets a new token, even in the same instance of the class. Within the class I'm using a singleton pattern for the `GraphServiceClient`.

Here is the code I'm using to handle the client:

```cs
private static GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;        
private static AuthenticationContext _authContext;
private static readonly object _locker = new();

private GraphServiceClient GetClient(M365ServiceOptions options)
{
    if (_graphServiceClient == null)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_graphServiceClient == null)
            {
                _authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{options.TenantId}/");
                var provider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    AuthenticationResult accessToken;
                    try
                    {
                        //Use Token from cache or refresh token
                        accessToken = await _authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(options.GraphURL, options.ClientId);
                        _logger.LogDebug("Cache Hit");
                    }
                    catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
                    {
                        //If no cached token, get a new one
                        _logger.LogDebug($"Cache Miss: {_authContext.TokenCache?.Count}");
                        var credentials = new ClientCredential(options.ClientId, options.ClientSecret);
                        accessToken = _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(options.GraphURL, credentials).Result;
                    }
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.AccessToken);
                });
                _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(provider);
            }
        }
    }
    return _graphServiceClient;
}
```

While debugging it is clear the token cache has an item in it, and the details all seem to match, but no matter what, the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` always throws the `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException` exception and forces it to get a new token for each call. This is impacting performance as no matter what, each call to the graph gets a new token.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Any success on that ? I'm facing the exact same problem right now.

Comment: @mberube.Net no, but with the latest update to the Graph SDK they have completely changed the authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this class. First call AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient() to get the a GraphServiceClient, then you this to access the user information.

```
public class AuthenticationHelper  
    {  
        static readonly string clientId = "";  
        public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };  
  
        public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(clientId);  
  
        public static string TokenForUser = null;  
        public static DateTimeOffset Expiration;  
  
        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;  
  
        // Get an access token for the given context and resourced. An attempt is first made to   
        // acquire the token silently. If that fails, then we try to acquire the token by prompting the user.  
        public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()  
        {  
            if (graphClient == null)  
            {  
                // Create Microsoft Graph client.  
                try  
                {  
                    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(  
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",  
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(  
                            async (requestMessage) =>  
                            {  
                                var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();  
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);  
                               
                                requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "MSGraphConsoleApp");  
  
                            }));  
                    return graphClient;  
                }  
  
                catch (Exception ex)  
                {  
                    Debug.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);  
                }  
            }  
  
            return graphClient;  
        }  
  
  
       
        public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()  
        {  
            AuthenticationResult authResult;  
            try  
            {  
                authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, IdentityClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result.First());  
                TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;  
            }  
  
            catch (Exception)  
            {  
                if (TokenForUser == null || Expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))  
                {  
                    authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes);  
  
                    TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;  
                    Expiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;  
                }  
            }  
  
            return TokenForUser;  
        }  
  
 
        public static void SignOut()  
        {  
            foreach (var user in IdentityClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result)  
            {  
                IdentityClientApp.RemoveAsync(user);  
            }  
            graphClient = null;  
            TokenForUser = null;  
  
        }  
  
    }
```

Comment: This seems to just move the token caching outside of the standard token cache, basically, this is saying, if there is a cache miss, check this other variable, and if that is empty, then get a new token. Doesn't that negate the need for the ```AcquireTokenSilentAsync``` completely?

Comment: def no. AcquireTokenSilentAsync will get an updated token without asking the user to enter his credentials.

Comment: In my code, no user is ever asked for their credentials, this is running as an application. My issue is that it never finds anything in the token cache, so it always gets a new token.